# convergence almost every where?

Tags: real-analysis

I have this question :

I found in a proof of a theorem this :

> Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , and $\phi \in D(\Omega)$ (the set of smooth functions with compact support in $\Omega$).

Then the autor says that the sequence $\phi_n(x)$ defined by $\phi_n(x)=n\phi(nx)$ for all $x\in\Omega$ converges a.e. to zero, so when $n\rightarrow\infty$ won't it be an indefined case (because $n\rightarrow\infty$ and $\phi(nx)$=0)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is this word "undeterminated"? It's not English.

Comment: sorry for my english , but in the case $\infty 0$ what can we say here ?

Comment: $or \frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Undetermined. Or indeterminate .Or undefined.(I've never seen "indeterminate" turned into a verb, but English has almost no rules so I guess it's ok. Outside of math,most people wouldn't understand "indeterminate" either.

Comment: I think it was pretty obvious he meant a limit of indeterminate form...

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi (0)=0$ then $n \phi (n\cdot 0)=0$ also.But otherwise  $\phi_n (0)$ doesn't converge. So in general $\lim_n \phi_n(x)$ may or may not be defined at $x=0$. I suppose that's what the author meant.

Comment: i don t understand what do you mean but here $n\rightarrow\infty$ !!

Comment: Of course.If $\phi(0)\ne 0$ then $\phi_n(0)=n\phi(0)$ doesn't converge to a real  or complex  number as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Lest there be any doubt -- convergence for $x\neq 0$ is a.e. convergence (in Lebesgue measure where $m(\{0\})=0$).  For $x\neq 0$ we have $nx\notin \sup(\phi)$ for sufficiently large $n$ because $\sup(\phi)$ is compact, so $\phi(nx)=0$ and $n\phi(nx)=0$ for large $n$ (how large is dependent on $x$ and $\phi$ of course).  Apologies if all this is too obvious.  (Oh, and I think the OP means "undefined" where he/she has written "indefined".)